# Script based Azure Alerts

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I would like to create an Azure Alert rule using the Azure Resource Graph tables, which are not available inside Azure Log Analytics. Using Azure CLI, a query can be sent to Azure Resource Graph ex:

```
az graph query "<QUERY>" --query count
```

Is it possible to create an Azure Alert based on the result of this query?

Comment: There are couple of ways to create an azure alert rule. It can be done through PowerShell as well as Azure CLI instead of running a query. If that is fine with you, I can provide you the solution in both ways.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to create an alert using `graph query`. Here are the approaches I worked on to create it.

***Approach-1:***

You can create it with the help of terraform running in `azCLI`. Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74267206/azure-activity-log-alerts-are-not-working/74285529#74285529).

***Approach-2:***

Using `scheduled query` parameter for `az monitor`command, I created an alert within the given scope as per your requirement.

I've tried creating a sample alert and it worked for me.

```bash
az monitor scheduled-query create -g "xxxxresourcegroup" -n "xxxalert" --scopes "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourcegroups/xxxxresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxxxVMName" --condition "count 'Placeholder_1' > 360 resource id _ResourceId at least 1 violations out of 5 aggregated" --condition-query Placeholder_1="union Event | where TimeGenerated > ago(3h) | where EventLevelName=='xxxxxError' or SeverityLevel=='xxxerror'" --description "xxxxxxxxx"
```

*Output:*

[image]

***Approach-3:***

By using `az monitor metrics alert` in `azCli`, you can build it without using a query.

I've taken a sample alert to check the condition of CPU (CPU %>50) and was able to perform it as shown here:

```bash
az monitor metrics alert create -n alert1 -g "xxxxxresourcegroup" --scopes "/subscriptions/< Subscription_ID >/resourcegroups/<resourcegroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxVMName" --condition "avg Percentage CPU > 50" --description "CPU Percentage"
```

*Output:*

[image]

***Approach-4:***

Usually, we can create an alert rule by executing a log query from required resource and then create a new alert rule.

I tried with an example query to check for missing software updates on virtual machine logs.

[image]

Click on `New alert rule` and `search query` will be automatically updated and select how to summarize the results.

[image]

Add `Alert logic`. When the threshold value of 50 is reached for an assigned event, an alert is fired via sending an email.

[image]

After an alert is fired, you can select an action from action group if you have already defined, else create one before an alert is triggered.

[image]

Provide Alert rule name and required details.

[image]

***New alert rule is created successfully.***

[image]

Reference: [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/scheduled-query?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your detailed answer! However, the issue here is that The resource graph tables are not part of Azure monitor (Log analytics, metrics, ...) So for example I want to monitor if Azure Arc connections are healthy, those logs are only present in the Resource Graph tables not in the Azure monitor tables. So my question was if it is possible perhaps using terraform (data external resource) to run this cli command (in the question) and then based on the result trigger an alert. Something like a custom metric but not exactly. Thanks again